# Manage multiple email addresses on multiple domains

Tags: email, email-client, email-server

I have about 10 different domains for different websites/projects I manage, and each one has a half dozen users for myself, admin, and some staff.

Is a way to put all of this in one place?  Hosting and managing all of these accounts separately is a nightmare.  I want to easily be able to log in and read/reply to emails, as well as add new email addresses.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: We need a few more details to be able to answer this – remember this site is about recommending software, not [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185) etc. So: Do you host those mail servers yourself? Are they all running on the same server? What server software is currently used (so the "management software" should support that)? I e.g. use Postfix Admin to maintain multiple domains on a single server, running Postfix (SMTP) and Dovecot (IMAP), and it serves me quite well.